# Spring Data JPA Implementation one to one relationship

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to implement Spring Data JPA one to one relationship and I have problems. I have a table of employees and a table of employees details. In the employee table I have a column employeeId and in table EmployeeDetail I have column employeeId. So when I add an employee foreign key to the table the employee details are automatically increased.

This is me entites:

`Employee:`

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private EmployeeDetail employeeDetail;
```

`EmployeeDetail:`

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "employeeId")
private Employee employee;
```

---

This is my class `EmployeeServiceImpl` and method to save Employee and EmployeeDetail is also involved.

```
public Employee saveEmployee(Employee employee) {

    EmployeeDetail employeeDetail = employee.getEmployeeDetail();
    employeeDetail.setEmployee(employee);
    employee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
    return employee;

}
```

In EmployeeController I have this two methods to show form for add new employee and to store new employee:

```
 @GetMapping("/showFormForAdd")
public String showFormForAdd(Model theModel) {

    // create model attribute to bind form data
    Employee theEmployee = new Employee();

    theModel.addAttribute("employee", theEmployee);

    return "addNewEmployeeForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/addNewEmployee",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Employee addNewEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") @RequestBody Employee employee) {
    Employee employeeResponse = employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
    return employeeResponse;
}
```

And this is just part of `.jsp` form for add new employee:

```
 <form:form action="addNewEmployee" modelAttribute="employee" method="POST">
```

As you can see, my model atribute is `employee` but its not recognized in my `.jsp` file in form.

In what way I can fix it? So when I create new employee his ID is automatic stored in EmployeeDetail? Or how I can add data to my related table(EmployeeDetail)?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware about how to directly store employee ID in details table when an employee is saved but what I would do is

1. Create an employee form, handle it through employee controller like below

```
    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String handleEmployeeForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());
        return "formEmployee";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee, Errors errors) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "formEmployee";
        }
        this.employeeService.save(employee);
        return "redirect:/employee/list";
    }

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listEmployees(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("employees", this.employeeService.findAll());
        return "listEmployee";
    }
```

2. Provide a link to add employee Details for an employee. I did this through a page which lists all employees(check /employee/list API of EmployeeController).

```
<a th:href="@{/employeeDetails/add/{employeeId}(employeeId=${employee.id})}" 
    th:each="employee : ${employees}"><span th:text="${employee.employeeEmail}"></span></a>
```

3. Create an employee details form, store employee id as hidden field in the form, handle it through employee details controller like below.

```
<input type="hidden"
                    class="form-control" th:field="*{employee.id}"/>
```

Employee Details Controller

```
    @GetMapping("/add/{employeeID}")
    public String handleEmployeeDetailsForm(@PathVariable long employeeID, Model model) {
        //create dummy employee 
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        //set id received from request to this employee object
        employee.setId(employeeID);
        
        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails = new EmployeeDetails();
        //set dummy employee object    
        employeeDetails.setEmployee(employee);
        model.addAttribute("employeeDetails", employeeDetails);
        return "formEmployeeDetails";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String saveEmployeeDetails(@ModelAttribute EmployeeDetails employeeDetails, Errors errors) {
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            return "formEmployeeDetails";
        }

        //fetch actual employee object from database
        Employee employee = this.employeeService.findById(employeeDetails.getEmployee().getId());

        //set to employee details object
        employeeDetails.setEmployee(employee);

        //save employee details object
        this.employeeDetailsService.save(employeeDetails);
        return "redirect:/listEmployeeDetails";
    }
```

**Edit 1** 
Another way of achieving your expected outcome is by modifying employee and employee details classes like below 
Employee

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private EmployeeDetail employeeDetail;
```

@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation tells that primary key of Employee will be used as foreign key in EmployeeDetails.

```
EmployeeDetail
@OneToOne
@MapsId
private Employee employee;
```

You will be saving EmployeeDetails here as its owning side (we defined mappedBy in Employee) and it will contain foreign key reference to Employee.

EmployeeDetailsController

```
@GetMapping("/add")
    public String handleEmployeeForm(Model model) {
        EmployeeDetails employeeDetails = new EmplyeeDetails();
        employeeDetails .setEmployee(new Employee());
        model.addAttribute("employeeDetails", employeeDetails );
        return "formEmployee";
    }

@PostMapping("/add")
    public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employeeDetails") EmployeeDetails employeeDetails) {
        this.employeeDetailsService.save(employeeDetails);
        return "redirect:/employee/add";
    }
```

Comment: The answer requires some sort of code snippets

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @BirhanNega Done.. Updated comment with code snippet.